# What is Javascript FunctionList?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I was playing an online game named `untrusted`, which is played by writing code.
There are some syntax that I've never seen before and couldn't find one the web. Can someone explain this to me?

```
functionList['movePlayerToExit'] = function () {
    map.writeStatus("Permission denied.");
}

functionList['pleaseMovePlayerToExit'] = function () {
    map.writeStatus("I don't think so.");
}

functionList['movePlayerToExitDamnit'] = function () {
    map.writeStatus("So, how 'bout them <LOCAL SPORTS TEAM>?");
}
```

Please explain the what is `functionList`, thank you!

And for those who are familiar with this game, please don't spoil, thank you again!

Comment: It's an object. What it is *exactly* in your application would be hard to say.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Maybe an example? Thank you!

Comment: See the answer I just typed in.

Comment: Besides using a somewhat less conventional notation the lines also miss `;`.

Comment: I got it, thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people would write

```
functionList['movePlayerToExit'] = ...
```

as

```
functionList.movePlayerToExit = ...
```

It's just ordinary JavaScript object property reference syntax. Since those strings would be valid if used as identifiers, there's no need to use the `[ ]` syntax.

Thus, if it's not clear, `functionList` is an object. Exactly what it means in the code you're looking at, I can't say. It looks like some sort of dispatch object, so that an operation code like "movePlayerToExit" can be looked up and the corresponding function invoked:

```
var actionCode = getActionCode(totallyMakingThisUp);
if (functionList[actionCode] != null)
  functionList[actionCode]();
```

Note that in that made-up example, it *is* necessary to use `[ ]` to access the properties of `functionList`, because the property name is stored in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

It is **probably** just an object where functions are assigned to keys (properties):

```
var obj = {};

obj["foo"] = function () { ... };
obj["bar"] = function () { ... };
```

Is the same as:

```
var obj = {
    "foo": function () { ... },
    "bar": function () { ... }
};
```

Just like a map.

However, it is possible it is an instance of a class which overrides the square bracket operator such as `Array`, `Map`, `WeakMap`, etc. But that doesn't really define a different behaviour.

Comment: It would also work for: `var obj = function(){};` or `var obj = [];`

Comment: @Jonathan That's true, but a `Function` is-a `Object`, just like a `Array`.